# Problemas com dependências de pacotes Maven

Tags: java-ee, jsf-2.2, maven

Quando vou inserir esse pacote ele gera um erro, porque será?

```
        <!-- Abstração para envio de e-mails -->        
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.outjected</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-email</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o erro que é gerado?

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente, você possui apenas os repositórios padrões do Maven e nenhum que possa resolver esta dependência.

Como `simple-email` não está nos repositórios que são padrões você deverá adicionar um repositório que resolva tal dependência.

Aparentemente tal biblioteca não está em um repositório público, pelo menos não encontrei, se você encontrar tal dependência em algum repositório público, você pode incluir no seu `pom.xml`, algo deste tipo:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>simple-email-repo</id>
        <url>http://urldorepositorio.com/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Ou incluir no seu `settings.xml`, uma forma é esta:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>simple-email</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>simple-email-repo</id>
                <url>http://urldorepositorio.com/repo</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Então, a forma mais simples de solucionar é:

1. [**Você precisará usar [git](/questions/tagged/git) neste passo**] Clone o repositório da biblioteca: `git clone https://github.com/codylerum/simple-email.git`
2. Caminhe até a pasta em que foi feito o clone: `cd simple-email`
3. [**Você precisará ter o [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) configurado corretamente no seu SO**] Instale a biblioteca no seu repositório local do maven: `mvn install -DskipTests=true` (os testes estão falhando, então não iremos rodá-los)
4. Depois de instalado com sucesso, atualize a dependência no seu `pom.xml` para a versão `0.2.1`, que é a versão atual do projeto que foi clonado, ficando assim:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.outjected</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-email</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**P.S. 1**: caso seu projeto ainda não possua dependência de `simple-mail`, você pode considerar usar alguma outra biblioteca que está no repositório central do maven, como [Simple Java Mail](https://github.com/bbottema/simple-java-mail), [Apache Common Email](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/), etc.

**P.S. 2**: um outro meio de solucionar é incluir o projeto do qual `simple-email` é *fork*, o [Seam Mail](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/3.1.0.Final/reference/en-US/html/pt08.html), caso seja conveniente para o seu caso.